# What is the smallest possible size of a bid/ask on Mt.Gox?

Tags: mtgox

I've successfully done .01 of a bitcoin for both bid and ask, but I'm wondering if someone knows the real limit?

I cant seem to find it in their documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the (unofficial) [MtGox API documentation](https://bitbucket.org/nitrous/mtgox-api/overview):

```
The minimum trade size to buy OR sell is 0.01 BTC
```

Comment: I believe you can make orders of less: http://i.imgur.com/cGjIS9x.png but maybe MtGox has fixed this now?